# Update extra user data through Ninja Forms on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, metadata, ninja-forms

I have created a form using Ninja Forms, where users give some answers for some questions and create a score. I have calculated the scores in Ninja Forms, and I need to update that score as a user field. I have created the field using Profile Extra Fields plugin. I've seen the Custom Form Action and Hook Tag part, but I have no idea how to write the code and implement it. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention to do it programatically here is one way of doing it (you can probably paste this in your functions.php, but preferably you should create custom plugin):

First register a new action:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_register_actions', 'register_my_nf_action' );
function register_my_nf_action( $actions ) {
    $actions['my_action_name'] = new MyActionClass();
    return $actions;
}
```

Then create a class:

```
class MyActionClass extends NF_Abstracts_Action {
    protected $_name     = 'my_action_name';
    protected $_timing   = 'late';
    protected $_priority = '100';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_nicename = esc_html__( 'My Action', 'text-domain' );
    }

    public function save( $action_settings ) {
        // You don't need to implement anything here
    }

    public function process( $action_settings, $form_id, $data ) {
        // Check if user is logged in (WordPress)
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            // some logic here
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', 'your_meta_value' );
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Make sure to add custom action to your form and save the form before testing it.